# Scrapy - How to pause on Connection loss and Resume when connection back on?

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, scrapy

Does anybody have an idea on how to pause the Scrapy crawler when the Internet connection is lost, and resume the crawler when the connection is back on?

There is a middleware for this, and I'm looking into that. Another option is -
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If yes, then you should probably add it here.

Comment: Nope. Had to develop micro modules and crawl in bursts.

Comment: Anyone found the solution ?

Comment: Scrapy pause and resume in not made for internet connection lost pause resume.